Power BI with JIRA API
I am trying to load stories from a specific release in JIRA into Power BI using the following JQL.
https://issues.xxx.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project in (ROL1) AND issuetype=Story&startAt=0&maxResults=100&id=ROL1-5998.
However, it seems I am not getting the required data.
Does anyone know what is the query to get all stories from a release?
Although, I specified a story, it seems the query is returning more than 100 stories. Is there a way to retrieve a story from using JIRA API? I am using the Web connector in Power BI
